# MySQL: Build a view having columns with data dependent on another view

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble creating a view that is dependent on the conditions of another table.

So view A consists of 2 columns of data. Column A is the DATE and column B is data for the particular date.

view B also consists of 10 columns with Column A as the DATE and column B has corresponding "Attributes" to column B in view A.

I'm trying to create a new view that consists of data from view A and view B with the following conditions.

- View C will have the same data as view A but with a condition.
- If the data point in view B = 0, then view C's data point will have the previous row's data from view A.

so for example:

This is what View C Should look like:
[Data View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dF0X.png)

I hope this is clear enough, but please let me know if this needs more explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will give you the previous row's data, but not the repetition of the last value like your example:

```
create view `View_c` as
select 
a.date,
case b.data
    when 0 then a.data
    else b.data end as data
from View_a a
left join View_b b on b.date = date_add(a.date, interval -1 day)
where a.data 'meets your condition'
```

Are you trying to repeat the value down like that, or pull in the previous day's row?

Comment: Thanks so much Jake. I'm trying to repeat the latest value of 'a' if the value of 'b' = 0. So in view C, the reason why date 5/30/18 has value 6.2 is because 1) view B on 5/30/18 = 0  and 2) the latest value was 6.2 because that was 5/28/18's value and view B = 0 on 5/29/18. Man...I hope that made sense and didn't make it even more confusing.